# Rename files in subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rename, batch-rename

I want to rename some files "folder.jpg" to "cover.jpg". The files itself are located two levels below of the current directory. A simple call

```
mv */*/folder.jpg */*/cover.jpg
```

does not work.

So...how can this be done automatically for all subdirectories?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it recursively? Like `mv -R */*/folder.jpg */*/cover.jpg`?

Comment: or look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed

Comment: @Schwesi both -R and -r are invalid options for mv :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for this:

```
find ./your-top-dir/ -iname 'folder.jpg' -execdir mv -i '{}' cover.jpg \;
```

Comment: This deleted all my files folder.jpg :-(

Comment: Damn! So sorry! I forgotten `-execdir` for the command to take place in the folder itself hence all `mv` commands gets executed on the calling folder which resulted in moving all to the same `./cover.jpg` file in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

For purposes of this answer, I am calling the directory below the current directory `dir1`, and the directory below that `directory2`.  The move command would then look like this:

```
mv dir1/dir2/folder.jpg dir1/dir2/cover.jpg
```

Comment: That would work if there was only one file — but the question clearly says that there are multiple files, in multiple directories (e.g., `dir1a/dir2a`, `dir1a/dir2b`, `dir1b/dir2a`, `dir1b/dir2b`, etc.) … … P.S. Your answer isn’t even internally consistent; you say you’re calling the second directory “directory2”, but your command says `dir2`.

Comment: to revise my answer, to move multiple files with a common part of their name such as the extension use the following

Comment: to revise my answer, to move multiple files with a common part of their name such as the extension, use the following:

Comment: to revise my answer, to move multiple files with a common part  of their name such as an extension, use mv *.x ./dir1/dir2/ where x is the common extension.

Comment: (1) If you want to revise your answer, [edit] it. (2) You’re still not getting it.  There isn’t a “common part of their name such as the extension”; *all* the source files have *exactly* the same name: `folder.jpg`.  And there isn’t *one* target directory; there are multiple directories that contain files (one relevant file per directory), and the files are to be *renamed* (but not moved into a different directory).  You are not answering the question.